# How to store instances of the same object in PHP (stateless)?

Tags: php, stateless, php-5.5

I was looking at "Pimple", Fabien Potencier's "simple service container" for PHP, and I was intrigued by the following comment:

> By default, each time you get a service, Pimple returns the same instance of it. If you want a different instance to be returned for all calls, wrap your anonymous function with the factory() method.

Based on how PHP is executed, how on earth would this be possible? Wouldn't PHP give me a new instance of an object every time a PHP script was executed?

EDIT: Pimple link - https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but to be clear - PHP **does** always give you a new instance of a class every time a script is run, e.g. a login class that is instantiated on every page of a website has a new instance of itself created every time you open a page.

Comment: The docs are not implying persistence across executions, rather that calling for a service creation multiple times in the same script will return the same object, unless wrapped in the factory method.

Comment: Drat, I was hoping this was some Fabien Potencier magic.

Comment: Ah thanks. Figured I was taking it out of context

Answer (score 0):

Answering this, because nobody in my comments did. The answer - you can't! PHP over HTTP is stateless, and I took the pimple documentation out of context.

If you need to achieve this, you should look into a cache system (APC, memcached) or an object server (Redis).

Thanks for the clarification.